# How to send json request in this format

Tags: android

I want to send json request in this format

```
"coordinates":{"0":{"received_at":1471529314,"lat":28.6888798,"long":77.3247225}}
```

but i am able to send the request in this format

```
{"coordinates":{"0":{"received_at":1471529314,"lat":28.6888798,"long":77.3247225}}}
```

I am using this code

```
            jsonObject.put("received_at", now);
            jsonObject.put("lat", latitude);
            jsonObject.put("long", longitude);
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("0",jsonObject);
            jsonObject1 = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject1.put("coordinates",json);
            Log.e("JSON",jsonObject1.toString());
```

Comment: Is the only difference in removing the first and last bracket?

Comment: Yes bracket is only difference @MuratK.

Answer (score 5):

The first request you are sharing is not valid JSON. A JSON string must always start with a `{` to indicate a JSONObject or with a `[` to indicate a JSONArray. 
If you insist on having the first format, I think you would have to build that string by yourself

Answer (score 0):

To remove the first and last bracket use this

```
String specialString = jsonObject1.toString().substring(1, jsonObject1.toString().length() - 1);
```